# Comparação de Resultados da Array()

Tags: php

Tenho um Array() de resultados, preciso comprar se a cidade do array 0, é igual a cidade do array 1, se a cidade do array 1 é igual a cidade do array 2... e assim sucessivamente.

O print_r do meu SQL resultou isto:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [tiposervico] => 0
            [endereco] => RUA CARLOS DE LAET
            [numero] => 1275
            [cidade] => 1
            [bairro] => 2
            [falarcom] => ADRIANO
            [idChamada] => 79
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [tiposervico] => 1
            [endereco] => 
            [numero] => 
            [cidade] => 1
            [bairro] => 11
            [falarcom] => 
            [idChamada] => 79
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [tiposervico] => 1
            [endereco] => 
            [numero] => 
            [cidade] => 2
            [bairro] => 316
            [falarcom] => 
            [idChamada] => 79
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [tiposervico] => 1
            [endereco] => 
            [numero] => 
            [cidade] => 2
            [bairro] => 327
            [falarcom] => 
            [idChamada] => 79
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [tiposervico] => 1
            [endereco] => 
            [numero] => 
            [cidade] => 1
            [bairro] => 21
            [falarcom] => 
            [idChamada] => 79
        )

)
```

Alguém conseguiria me dizer uma forma de elaborar essa comparação em PHP?

Elaborei o código php da seguinte forma:

```
        $contagemTrechoInicial = 0;
        for($contagemTrechos=0; $contagemTrechos<=count($dados)-1; $contagemTrechos++){
            $contagemTrechoInicial++;
            if($dados[$contagemTrechos]['cidade']==$dados[$contagemTrechoInicial]['cidade']) 
                echo "<br>Iguais > (".$dados[$contagemTrechos]['cidade'].")";   
            else echo "<br>Diferentes > (".$dados[$contagemTrechoInicial]['cidade'].")";
        }
```

Mas como ele é $contagemTrechoInicial++; ele sempre busca um array a mais, o que gera um erro de Undefined offset: 5.

Como eu posso ajustar para que funcione corretamente?

Obs: O resultado dessa comparação deverá ser:

```
Trecho 1: Cidade 1 > Cidade 1 - iguais
Trecho 2: Cidade 1 > Cidade 2 - diferentes
Trecho 3: Cidade 2 > Cidade 2 - iguais
Trecho 4: Cidade 2 > Cidade 1 - diferentes
```

Comment: Coloca `$contagemTrechoInicial++;` depois do `else`.

Comment: Se eu colocar depois do Else, ele diz que todos são iguais... E não está correto, é um comparativo de multi trechos: o resultado deverá ser: 

Trecho 1: Cidade 1 > Cidade 1 - iguais
Trecho 2: Cidade 1 > Cidade 2 - diferentes
Trecho 3: Cidade 2 > Cidade 2 - iguais
Trecho 4: Cidade 2 > Cidade 1 - diferentes

Comment: Começa a variável com valor `1`. E deixa depois do `else`.

Comment: O erro é o mesmo dai... Dá o erro na array 5, que não existe, por que neste caso vai até o 4... mas podem ser inseridos outros trechos, por isso precisa ser dinamico

Comment: verifique se o indice existe antes fazer a comparação, use `isset()`, 
`if(isset($dados[$contagemTrechoInicial]['cidade']){ ... `

Comment: Com esse seu isset deu certo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Percebi que conseguiu com a sugestão do @rray, mas segue uma forma
>   alternativa para fazer o algoritmo de comparação de trechos.

```
$trechos = array(
        array("cidade" => 1),
        array("cidade" => 1),
        array("cidade" => 2),
        array("cidade" => 2),
        array("cidade" => 1)
);

$indiceAtual = 1;
$limite = count($trechos);

while ($indiceAtual < $limite) {
    $indiceAtual = $indiceAtual - 1;
    for ($x = 1; $x <= 2; $x++) {
        $cidade[] = $trechos[$indiceAtual]['cidade'];
        $indiceAtual++;
    }
    if ($cidade[0] == $cidade[1]) {
        echo 'iguais';
    }else{
        echo 'diferentes';
    }
    unset($cidade);
    echo '<br>';
}
```

**Output:**

```
iguais // 11
diferentes // 12
iguais // 22
diferentes // 21
```

### Explicando as partes mais importantes

O `while` executa enquanto o total de índices do `array` de trechos não for atingido.

No `for` eu pego dois **trechos** *(cidades)* por vez e coloco cada um deles no vetor `$cidade`. Assim eu posso comparar cada dupla de trechos por vez no `if`.